# Android start same activity/intent within web view

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-webview

I need to start a new activity when a user taps a link in my webview, currently this works when using separate layouts and independent shouldOverrideUrlLoading for each one but these links could be infinite so I can't do that.

How do I start the same Activity/Intent each time a user taps a link when I'm already in the Activity I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all I actually had to do was change my activities launch mode from `singleTop` to `standard` in my manifest file.

That's **7 hours** I'll never get back.